# Convert HashMap to string comma separated

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap

I have a class `ShoppingCartHelper` and a method.

```
private static Map<Product, ShoppingCartEntry> cartMap = new HashMap<Product, ShoppingCartEntry>();
```

And method that stores data product to cartMap:

```
public static List<Product> getCartList() {
    List<Product> cartList = new Vector<Product>(cartMap.keySet().size());
    for(Product p : cartMap.keySet()) {
        cartList.add(p);
    }
    return cartList;
}
```

In other class I call stored data on map:

```
private List<Product> mCartList;
mCartList = ShoppingCartHelper.getCartList();
```

and print it in comma separated:

```
StringBuilder commaSepValueBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for ( int i = 0; i< mCartList.size(); i++) {
   commaSepValueBuilder.append(mCartList.get(i));
   if ( i != mCartList.size()-1) {
       commaSepValueBuilder.append(", ");
   }
}
System.out.println(commaSepValueBuilder.toString());
```

Its printed like `com.android.test@34566f3,com.android.test@29f9042`

How do I print data on Map to string (human readable)?

Answer (score 3):

Make your `Product` class overriding the `toString()` method or in your custom logic, make a string builder appending not the element itself, but it's fileds, which you wish to recieve as text description of the product instance. I mean something like this:

```
//since I don't know, what is the Product class, I supposed it has a name filed
commaSepValueBuilder.append(mCartList.get(i).getName());
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use [`Vector`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html), use [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). Quoting javadoc:

> If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use `ArrayList` in place of `Vector`

The shorter version of `getCartList()` is:

```
public static List<Product> getCartList() {
    return new ArrayList<>(cartMap.keySet());
}
```

As for how to build comma-separated list of products, the best way is to implement the `Product` method `toString()`. This will also help when debugging.

```
public class Product {

    // lots of code here

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getName(); // Assuming Product has such a method
    }
}
```

Then you can use [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) in a simple `for-each` loop:

```
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
for (Product product : ShoppingCartHelper.getCartList()) {
    if (buf.length() != 0)
        buf.append(", ");
    buf.append(product); // or product.getName() if you didn't implement toString()
}
System.out.println(buf.toString());
```

In Java 8 that can be simplified by using [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html):

```
StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(", ");
for (Product product : ShoppingCartHelper.getCartList())
    sj.add(product);
System.out.println(sj.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override toString method in your Product class like below,

```
public class Product {

//sample properties
private String name;
private Long id;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Product{" +
            "name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", id=" + id +
            '}';
}
```

}

it can print string in human readable format.

Answer (score 0):

Override [toString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#toString(java.lang.Object)) in Product class and use Java 8 [Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) to make it more simpler, as below:

```
 mCartList.stream().map(e -> e.toString())
                .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

**Usage:**

```
List<Product> mCartList = new ArrayList<>();
        mCartList.add(new Product(1, "A"));
        mCartList.add(new Product(2, "B"));

        String commaSepValue = mCartList.stream().map(e -> e.toString())
                .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
        System.out.println(commaSepValue);
```

Product.java

```
final class Product {
        private final int id;
        private final String name;

        public Product(int id, String name) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Product [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + "]";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code works for me by using **Java 8** Streams:

**For Hashmap :**

```
hashmapObject.entrySet().stream().map(e -> e.toString())
                .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

**For List :**

```
listObject.stream().map(e -> e.toString())
                .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```